# Batch Script Fails - Cannot output text to file without quotations, however quotation marks are not desired

Tags: windows, batch-file, insert, sqlplus, quotes

I am trying to run a batch script that writes out a bunch of text to a .sql file that gets run in a SQL Command window. I am trying to have my batch script output a line of text that says:

insert into TEST_TABLE (param1, param2) values ('JohnSmith','Test1');

My code below as is does not work, CMD just crashes immediately upon running the .bat file:

```
@echo off

(
echo insert into TEST_TABLE (param1, param2) values ('JohnSmith','Test1');

) > TEST.sql

pause
```

However, when I change it and add quotes:

```
@echo off

(
echo "insert into TEST_TABLE (param1, param2) values ('JohnSmith','Test1');"

) > TEST.sql

pause
```

When I do this, it outputs the file as expected with the line of text in the file, however it has the quotes which I cannot have in there because that will cause SQL command to fail.

Can anyone please help me understand how to get this script to output this specific text to a .sql file without the quotes?

Thanks

Comment: You need to escape the right parentheses.

Comment: `(echo escape '^)' with a caret.)`

Comment: Do as others have suggested by escaping the right paren or remove the outer parens and put everything on one line so that you have this: echo insert into TEST_TABLE (param1, param2) values ('JohnSmith','Test1');> TEST.sql

Comment: Escaping the right parenthesis worked! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here. Use `set /P` command instead of `echo` to enclose the text in quotes (and show it with no quotes):

```
@echo off

< NUL (

set /P "=insert into TEST_TABLE (param1, param2) values ('JohnSmith','Test1');"
echo/

) > TEST.sql

pause
```

... or escape each right parentheses with a caret:

```
@echo off

(
echo insert into TEST_TABLE (param1, param2^) values ('JohnSmith','Test1'^);

) > TEST.sql

pause
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I couldn't figure out which item needed to be escaped, but now seeing the people doing the right parenthesis, I understand why and it seems kind of obvious...doh.

Comment: Two neat tricks in one.Using set /p to echo and escape enclosing quotes.Using a () block to redirect loads of echos  at once.